# Why is write access restricted in Apache Drill RDBMS storage plugin? Is there any possible workaround?

Tags: apache-drill

As far I know, there is no possibility to create [temporary] tables in relational databases from Drill. 
The RDBMS storage plugin does not allow it and it also does not allow to create workspaces, which are - I believe - necessary for defining write access.

1. What are exact reasons for this restrictions?
2. Is there any possible workaround (using drill) to create [temporary] tables in postgresql or mssql without writing own intermediate layer? IMHO, it could be really helpful.